# JDBC Connection for active director-universal MFA authentication

Tags: java, jdbc, active-directory, adal, adal4j

I need to connect to the sql server using Active directory-universal with MFA support. First, can we connect to it using JDBC connection string? Because it is an Interactive mode for authentication unlike Active directory Integrated and Active directory password, I dont think its possible to connect using JDBC. If my assumption is correct then, secondly, does it require .Net Framework?.
Any link or comment would be helpful. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following steps defined in [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication)

This includes steps using MFA also.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But that article doesn't explan how to connect it through JDBC.

Comment: After  a lot of research, it seems that JDBC connection is not supported for active Directory MFA authentication since it is an interactive mode of authentication.

Comment: @Rik. Did you find any alternative to use Active Directory MFA in jdbc?

Comment: No, @user2196474. Its been a long time since I asked that question but I remember I connected with microsoft itself and they said its not possible with MFA. As an alternative I asked the clients to have other modes of authentication like sql or windows. :)